# Silverstripe hash link rewriting putting unwanted slash in link

Tags: hash, hyperlink, url-rewriting, anchor, silverstripe

Ok so I am developing a site in Silverstripe CMS that is using anchor links on one of it's pages. Thing is that in Silverstripe there is a rewrite going on that puts slashes before the hash in your links.

So in the docs it explains that you can put this in your YAML to disable slashes before hashes: http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/disable_anchor_links/

Which I have done like so (YAML validates ok):

_config/app.yml:

```
SSViewer: rewrite_hash_links: false
```

And then in my template file this is how I am constructing my link with anchor:

```
<a href="$ParentPage.Link#$URLSegment">Link</a>
```

(note that this template file is for a dataobject, I'm not sure if that has any baring)

And the outputted link is:

/cnc-machining/#made-to-order

but should be:

/cnc-machining#made-to-order

I'm all out of ideas. Any pointers?

Comment: Could you make your own Link function and there remove the trailing Slash?

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried this and it had the same results. Anyway not to worry I think I can just work around this for now. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DataObject's getLink() method you can simply remove the trailing slash using [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim):

```
public function getLink() {
    //remove trailing slash from parent link
    $parentLink = rtrim($this->ParentPage()->Link(), '/'); 
    return $parentLink . '#' . $this->URLSegment;
}
```

Now in your template just run in DataObject's scope:

```
<a href="$Link">Link</a>
```

Though i didn't notice any disadvantage with having the trailing slash in the url.

HTH, wmk

Comment: Glad i could help you. Feel free to "accept" the answer ;)