# silverstripe slash in url file location

Tags: silverstripe

I recently came across this post on removing the slash in the URL which is what I am trying to achieve.

[Silverstripe hash link rewriting putting unwanted slash in link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365057/silverstripe-hash-link-rewriting-putting-unwanted-slash-in-link/34816670#34816670)

I was hoping someone might be able to expand on the answer given?

Reason:
I'm struggling to find the file location to carry out the edit on SS version 3.2.1

I'm new to SS and creeping along in the slow lane at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps this will help you. How to solve this is described in the SilverStripe Docs https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/disable_anchor_links/

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you please describe what you are trying to do, where the problem is, your desired outcome and share what you have tried?